# How can i display data of an api one after another on the basis of id in react js.?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios, es6-promise

So basically what iam trying to do is to get data from an api using axios get one after another for example Q1 what is your name (user answers it and then clicks next) Next Q2 what is your hobby(user answers it and then clicks next) than Q3,4,5,6 etc i want to display limited amount of data from an api which consists of array of 63 questions.I want o build a questionare where questions are displayed after the user answers the previous one.[image: Here you can see my apis containing data]

Mycode is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios'
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Questionare extends Component {
  state = {
    items: []
  };


componentDidMount() {
  Axios.get('http://leaty-dev.azurewebsites.net/')
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.setState({ items: response.data.result.items });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

    render() { 
      const { items } = this.state;
       return (
        <div>
          <button className="btn" >Click</button>
          <ul>
            {items.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id}>{item.pqDetail}</li>
        ))}
          </ul>
          </div>
       )
    }

}

export default Questionare;
```

Comment: Store question counter on state. After user response for previous question - increase a counter by 1. And then you can show/hide question depends on the counter and question index (from map function). `{questionCount === index && <li...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick items one after the other and set as currentItem and then render currentItem to view.

```
mport React, { Component } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios'
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Questionare extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [],
    currentItem: null,
    index: 0
  };


componentDidMount() {
  Axios.get('http://leaty-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/services/app/PersonalityQuestioner/GetAllPersonalityQuestioner')
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.setState({ items: response.data.result.items, currentItem: response.data.result.items[0], index: 0 });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

handleNext = () => {
    const { index, items } = this.state;
    const nextQuestion = index + 1;

    this.setState({ currentItem: items[nextQuestion], index: nextQuestion });
}

    render() { 
      const { currentItem } = this.state;
       return (
        <div>
          <button className="btn" onClick={this.handleNext}>Next</button>
          <ul>
          <li key={currentItem.personalityQuestionerCategory.id}>{currentItem.pqDetail}</li>
          </ul>
          </div>
       )
    }

}

export default Questionare;
```

Comment: My questions are stored in that api @ioedeveloper from where i should modify the end point

Comment: No i cant it gives 404 whenever i try to set an endpoint of that api

Comment: Okay, then you'll have to structure the display of your questions in chunks coming one after another @AbdulRauf

Comment: Thank you so much brother I really appreciate that just one last thing it says. Cannot read property 'id' of null

Comment: Its line 37 in <li> tag

Comment: Okay, it should be `currentItem.personalityQuestionerCategory.id` @AbdulRauf

Comment: `console.log(this.state)` so we can be sure the data is fetched. @AbdulRauf

Answer (score 1):

Store a index in your state:

```
state = {
    items: [],
    index: 0
};
```

Inside your button's `onClick` function's `setState` which I assume you have one to store the user's answers add the line `index: this.state.index + 1`.

Inside `render` store the `index` to a variable: `const index = this.state.index;`

And instead of using `.map` you render the question like this:

```
<ul>
  <li key={items[index].id}>
    {items[index].pqDetail}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my working solution using JavaScript **Generators**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

class Questionare extends Component {
  item = this.itemGenerator();
  state = {
    items: [],
    currentItem: "Click to get a series of question one after another"
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get(
      "http://leaty-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/services/app/PersonalityQuestioner/GetAllPersonalityQuestioner"
    )
      .then(({ data: { result: { items } } }) => this.setState({ items }))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  *itemGenerator() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      const item = items[i].pqDetail;
      yield item;
    }
  }

  handleButtonClick = () => {
    const currentItem = this.item.next().value;
    this.setState({ currentItem });
  };

  render() {
    const { currentItem } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <button className="btn" onClick={this.handleButtonClick} 
        disabled={!currentItem}>
          Click
        </button>
        {currentItem && <Fragment>{currentItem}</Fragment>}
        {!currentItem && <Fragment>No Questions Available</Fragment>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Questionare;
```